# Workflow with Laravel & Swagger / OpenAPI

Tags: laravel, swagger, lumen, swagger-codegen, openapi

I'm currently working on an API which is based on OpenAPI 3.0 / Swagger.

I find the API docs & code generation extremely useful, but what happens when a simple thing in the API changes?

I would generate a new Server (based on Lumen / Laravel) and copy over the script files and every old code is gone or i would have to merge the code.

Is there a more elegant way to have this kind of incremental workflow for designing APIs with Swagger / OpenAPI and Laravel / Lumen?